# Difference between "on the both sides" and "on both sides"

Tags: differences

I really do not have any idea about the difference between the two phrases "on the both sides" and "on both sides". They both appear a lot from Google search.
I see the the first phrase in this sentence "Green grass is on the both sides of the river."
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The usage 'on the both sides' is a colloquialism. Correct English would be 'on both sides'